# How to Make Mutual Exclusive chechkboxs with on checkbox is checked on window loaded in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

*I have three check boxes Namely, Document Submission,Document Pickup and Others. I made this three check Boxes Mutually Exclusive to each other as Below*

```
<Grid Height="303" Width="500">
        <ListBox Name="ListBox1" Margin="49,67,86,164">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush
                       x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                       Color="White"/>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="White" IsItemsHost="True"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" IsThreeState="True"   IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"  Content="{Binding}" BorderThickness="1" AllowDrop="False" Focusable="True"  Background="White" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

*List Box is Bind on Window loaded as Follows*

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("Documnet Pickup");
    lst.Add("Document Submission");
    lst.Add("Others");
    ListBox1.ItemsSource = lst;
}
```

*How can i make one check box is checked on window loaded. Is this a best approach?.*

Comment: If you make them radio buttons, doesn't the mutually exclusive thing come with?  Why checkboxes instead of radio buttons?

Comment: **yeah i achieved this by Radio Button. But this is according to our Requirement** Above code gives me mutually exclusive check Boxes only thing i cannot able to do is to make on check box cheeked whenever window is loaded.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't follow good UX guidelines, IMO. Radio buttons imply mutual exclusivity. Check boxes do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're binding checkbox `IsChecked` property to listbox item `IsSelected` property here :

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
```

You can simply set listbox selected index to index of an item, for example, the first item :

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("Documnet Pickup");
lst.Add("Document Submission");
lst.Add("Others");
ListBox1.ItemsSource = lst;
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

then the respective item will automatically has checkbox checked.

Comment: Thanx this works Out :). one last Question Regarding this. The Background Color become gray on this list box Item(checked Checkbox) on window loaded. After clicking another check box it removes out. Also when i go to other control such as textBox again the checkbox(List Box items) become gray. Any idea : Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the last line to your function. It makes the first checkbox checked.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("Documnet Pickup");
    lst.Add("Document Submission");
    lst.Add("Others");
    ListBox1.ItemsSource = lst;
    ListBox1.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: There is no options  ListBox1.Items[0]. **Selected** in this code. Thanx

Comment: Oh, how about `ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;` instead?

Comment: * Thanks** This works Out :). one last Question Regarding this. The Background Color become gray on this list box Item(checked Checkbox) on window loaded. After clicking another check box it removes out. Also when i go to other control such as textBox again the checkbox(List Box items) become gray.  Any idea : Thanx